# Custom user location marker with custom accuracy circle in MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm implementing simple navigation and to display user location I'm using custom **MKAnnotationView**:

```
let reuseId = "userLocationPin"
userLocationViewAnnotation = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
if userLocationViewAnnotation == nil {

    userLocationViewAnnotation = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    userLocationViewAnnotation!.canShowCallout = true
    userLocationViewAnnotation!.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.9, y: -2)
    userLocationViewAnnotation!.image = UIImage(named: "User_location_red_moving_x1")

}
```

And this code is working fine. Next I need to add accuracy circle. I'm adding it by **MKCircle** overlay:

```
userLocationCircle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: location.coordinate, radius: location.horizontalAccuracy)
map.addOverlay(userLocationCircle!)
```

The problem is that user location is updating more frequently and with animation by MKMap internally, but circle is updating after user location change (in my code) so it's jumping from one point to another.

Is it possible to add this circle to MKAnnotationView, or maybe do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Hey Michal, did you ever find a proper solution to your problem? I am currently facing the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1** (which I did before)

Do not set `MKMapView.showsUserLocation` to true. Which means that you cannot use  `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` of the delgate any more. That means that fetching the user's location is less convenient. You will have to use Core Location for that. (Tons of tutorials around) 
Then you have to set the map's center ans span accordingly but yourself. By doing so you can add any annotation that you want for the user's location. Just respond to `mapView(_:viewForAnnotation:)` and return the view that you want to be displayed.

**Solution 2:** (Which I guess works but I never tried it myself)

Just go along with MKMapView.showsUserLocation as you did before but respond to `mapView(_:viewForAnnotation:)` in any case. Debug it. On the first call to this method it is handed in the standard user annotation. (I just don't know its type/class name out of the top of my head. It is the first one. That's why I ask you to debug for it.) 
Just don't return nil but return the view that you want to be displayed.

It is worth a try. It is less work than solution 1 if it works.

However, solution 1 gives you much more flexibilty and full control over the part of the world that is currently displayed in the Map.

Comment: I don't understand Solution 2, now I'm returning my custom view in `mapView(_:viewForAnnotation:)`, not nil, and this view don't have a circle it's a simple spot. This method is executed only once on the beginning, not on every location/annotation update.

Comment: And what result do you get? 

As I said I never tried that myself. The idea just came up.

Comment: I'm describing result in my question, annotation is updating very frequently and smoothly but circle jumps from one point to another